# Template not reflecting change when more records are added to the store

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to implement a 'load more' button at the end of my list template but when I update the store with more records, my list isn't being updated. Right now I'm just manually setting 'content' on my controller to update the list template.

```
App.AlbumsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...

  loadMore: function() {
    var that = this;

    this.incrementProperty('currentPage'); 

    App.Album.find({
      page: this.get('currentPage')
    }).on('didLoad', function() {
      that.set('content', App.Album.all())
    });
  }

  ...
})
```

I'm not convinced this is the best way to go about things so I'm wondering if there is a way to set bindings between the template and store so when I update the store with `App.Album.find(<params>)`my albums template gets automatically updated.